# Cucumber-Capybara: save_screenshot(path, full: true) is not capturing the full browser?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm using the latest Chrome browser, Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit), with the latest chromedriver v2.29 (although I've tried with Chrome 56 and chromedriver 2.27 as well) and I've got a problem where I am not able to capture the full browser when a test fails.

This is the code I've got on my env.rb file:

```
Capybara::Screenshot.register_driver(:chrome) do |driver, path|
  driver.browser.save_screenshot(path, full: true)
end
```

However, the screenshots I am getting are just a partial part, what I can see on the screen rather than the complete browser.

Any idea if I'm doing something wrong or if I can try something different?

Thank you!

Comment: what if you change it to `driver.browser.save_screenshot(path, :full => true)` ?

Comment: I've been doing more tests, just noticed that if I put "full: true" or ":full => true" inside that code for register_driver in my env.file then NO screenshot is taken. If I remove it, the screenshot is taken although cut.

Then I created a different step just with the save_screenshot function (ie, not inside register_driver) and in that case, I can capture a screenshot with any of those 2 options, however, the screenshot is still cut!! 

No idea what could be causing these 2 problems...

Comment: @fabersky  `full: true` and `:full => true` are the same thing.  The first is just an alternative syntax that was added in Ruby 1.9, it will never make a difference to replace one with the other.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using chrome, I assume you're using the selenium driver (selenium-webdriver).  The selenium driver doesn't support any options being passed to `save_screenshot`, and passing options to  `page.driver.screenshot` -https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb#L34 - will raise a too many arguments error (which in your case I assume the capybara_screenshot gem catches and ignores) and not save a screenshot.  If instead you call `driver.save_screenshot(path, full: true)` it will take a shot, but any options passed will be ignored since they aren't supported.  Additionally, since the WebDriver spec is defined as taking a shot of the viewport (visible window), I would not expect selenium to support full screen shots any time soon.

If you are using selenium for your screenshots and you want larger your only option is to increase the window size before taking your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation Thomas, I couldn't find what could be happening and thought I was just doing something wrong.

I'll mark it as fixed for now then as unsupported! Thanks!